# Where should I pay income taxes (Living abroad, working for a French company)

Tags: taxes, french-citizens, morocco

I am French citizen working for a French company, I work remotely from Morocco where I have been living for five years.

I used to work for a Moroccan company, therefore taxes where taken from my monthly salary.

I started working for a French company in September 2016. Income declarations are approaching and I don't know what I should do.

Except for up to two weeks of vacation, I live exclusively in Morocco where I have a 10 years residence card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a tax expert.

What usually happens is that you would be considered tax resident in Morocco, as you have lived there for 183 days or more in the year. This is especially true since you have been employed there and paid tax there before, and have a residence card there.

I would say that you should declare your earnings from the French company as overseas earnings when you prepare your Moroccan tax return. There is no need to file a tax return in France, as you are not considered resident in France for tax purposes.